# google analytics - User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile with other path age

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I have google analytics javascript code with googleapis npm.

And I authorize with jwt

below code is my authorize and parameters

```
siteUrl: string,
    startDate: string,
    endDate?: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    await this._jwt.authorize();

    const viewId = await this._getPropertyId(siteUrl);
    const params: Params$Resource$Data$Ga$Get = {
      auth: this._jwt,
      ids: 'ga:' + viewId,
      // 'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      // 'end-date': 'today',
      'start-date': startDate,
      'end-date': endDate || startDate,
      metrics: 'ga:users,ga:sessions',
    };

    const result = await this._analytics.data.ga.get(params);
    return result.data.totalsForAllResults;
```

viewId is value of ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or [www.example.com/other/pathe](http://www.example.com/other/pathe) ...)

and getPropertyId methos is below code

```
private async _getPropertyId(siteUrl: string): Promise<any> {
    await this._jwt.authorize();

    let propertyId = 0;
    const params: Params$Resource$Management$Accountsummaries$List = {
      auth: this._jwt,
    };
    const result: any = await this._analytics.management.accountSummaries.list(
      params,
    );

    result.data.items[0].webProperties.forEach((item: any) => {
      console.log(item.websiteUrl)
      if (item.websiteUrl === siteUrl) {
        propertyId = item.profiles[0].id;
      }
    });
```

Problem is I success my site main page tracking info (example: https://www.example.com)

but I failed in not main page (example: https://www.example.com/other/path)

with below error code

```
Error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

    at Gaxios._request (/.../.../node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:158:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at JWT.requestAsync (/.../.../node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:343:18)
```

I tried new google analytics property and activate "Create a Universal Analytics property" option But same..

how can i solve this proplem ??

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo I add auth and parameter code

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution 1**
This msg indicates the account you are using cannot access the Google Analytics view. Maybe Google Analytics account owner removes your access.
Also, expired connector license will result in random errors that include this one.

The easiest way to fix the issue is to open your account and see if the view is listed as one of the possible selections in the image

[image]

**Possible solution 2**

You need to create a universal analytics property.

1. In account click on "Create Property"
2. Fill the fields and click on "Show advance options"
3. Activate "Create a Universal Analytics property"
4. Add the website url in the field and then make sure "Create both a Google Analytics 4 ...." and "Enable enhanced measure
   interactions on your sites...." are marked.

Comment: I did solution2 but problem is same. Where is solution 1 image options ?

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

Means that your code is trying to access a profile id or view id that the user that you have authenticated with does not have access to.

```
ids: 'ga:' + viewId,
```

Go to google developer console and check that you have the correct view id.  Then check that when you login you are logging in with a user that does have access to that account.

Remember when sharing accounts with users that you should share at the account level to give them access to all views or profiles under the account.

[User doesn't have any google analytics accounts easy solution](https://youtu.be/s0fwl7tbS8U)

Comment: in (this._getPropertyId(siteUrl)) return my property id (www.example.com) but return 0 in other path(www.example/other/path)...  what is proble ...?